# Cant get value from VB class

Tags: vb.net, class, calculator

I am trying to make a simple, class based calculator in Visual Basic, but when I press the buttons (Add) (Multiply) it shows 0 as the value in the textbox.

Here is my code:
FORM 2:

```
Public Class Form2
Dim Class2 As part2Class = New part2Class()
Dim Class2b As part2ClassB = New part2ClassB()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Num1 As Integer = CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)
    Dim Num2 As Integer = CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)
    MessageBox.Show(Class2.Calculate().ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Num1 As Integer = CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)
    Dim Num2 As Integer = CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)
    MessageBox.Show(Class2b.Calculate())
End Sub
```

End Class

---

part2Class CLASS

```
Public Class part2Class

    Public Property Num1
    Public Property Num2

    Public Overridable Function Calculate() As Integer
        Return Num1 + Num2

    End Function
End Class
```

---

Part2ClassB

```
Public Class part2ClassB
    Inherits part2Class
    Public Overrides Function Calculate() As Integer
        Return Num1 * Num2
    End Function
End Class
```

When I put values in the textbox and press ADD/MULIPLY it shows 0 as the value.

[image: PICTURE OF ISSUE]

Comment: Have you debugged the code, i.e. set a breakpoint and stepped through it line by line, examining the state at each step?  If not, you need to do that before posting here.  Once you have done that, you'll be able to see EXACTLY where and how the code behaves contrary to your expectations.  You may even be able to fix the problem for yourself but, if not, at least you'll be able to tell us where to look and what to look for.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the values to the properties of your classes.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Num1 As Integer = CType(TextBox1.Text, Integer)
    Dim Num2 As Integer = CType(TextBox2.Text, Integer)

    Class2b.Num1=Num1
    Class2b.Num2=Num2
    MessageBox.Show(Class2b.Calculate())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CType` fails you will crash your program. I changed it to `TryParse` which sets the variable in the second parameter (in this case a property of the class) and returns `True` or `False`. The `AndAlso` stops as soon as it reaches a `False` and proceeds to the `Else` part of the `If`

You need to declare your properties with a datatype in your class. See my comment about Option Strict.

```
Public Class part2Class

    Public Property Num1 As Integer
    Public Property Num2 As Integer

    Public Overridable Function Calculate() As Integer
        Return Num1 + Num2
    End Function
End Class


Public Class part2ClassB
    Inherits part2Class
    Public Overrides Function Calculate() As Integer
        Return Num1 * Num2
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Class2 As part2Class = New part2Class()
        Dim message As String
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Class2.Num1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Class2.Num2) Then
            message = Class2.Calculate().ToString
        Else
            message = "Please enter a number in both text boxes."
        End If
        MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Class2b As part2ClassB = New part2ClassB()
    Dim message As String
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Class2b.Num1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, Class2b.Num2) Then
        message = Class2b.Calculate().ToString
    Else
        message = "Please enter a number in both text boxes."
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```